# how to specify a vault password file to molecule test?

Tags: ansible, molecule

When running tests with molecule:

```
molecule tests
```

and some files are protected with [ansible vault](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/vault.html), the **--vault-password-file** must be specified to provide the password to decrypt their content.

Although it is possible to do that with converge

```
 molecule converge -- --vault-password-file ~/.vault.txt
```

it fails with molecule tests

```
 $ molecule test -- --vault-password-file ~/.vault.txt
 Usage: molecule test [OPTIONS]
 Error: Got unexpected extra arguments (--vault-password-file ~/.vault.txt)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the [ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD_FILE](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#envvar-ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD_FILE) environment variable like so:

```
ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD_FILE=$HOME/.vault.txt molecule test
```

will bypass molecule arguments parsing logic and let ansible know where the vault password is located.

Answer (score 4):

You can pass the the password file to molecule via `provisioner.config_options.defaults.vault_password_file` in your `molecule.yml` file as follows:

```
provisioner:
  name: ansible
  config_options:
    defaults:
      vault_password_file: "${MOLECULE_SCENARIO_DIRECTORY}/vault.pw"
```

where `vault.pw` is a plain text file that contains only your password (Make sure this is well protected!)

The vault password file is an option passed over to Ansible directly and is defined [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/intro_configuration.html#vault-password-file)